# regex for four-digit numbers (or "default")

Tags: regex, xsd

I need a regex for four-digit numbers separated by comma ("default" can also be a value).

Examples:

1. `6755`
2. `3452,8767,9865,8766,3454`
3. `7678,9876`
4. `1234,9867,6876,9865`
5. `default`

Note: `"default"` alone should match, but `default,1234,7656` should NOT match.

Comment: Why regex - split on , and you have an array of values

Comment: What regex style? PCRE, POSIX, extended POSIX, Vim, etc.? What does your input look like? Are the examples the only text on the line or could it be in the middle of the line among other stuff?

Comment: @greg:my try-    default|\d{4}(\,\d{4})* does not work
@mark/@jamessan: have to use it in xsd

Comment: @jamessan: The examples i provided will cover all scenarios for the input. I need a generic regex.

Comment: @Subhasis: It looks like you've asked the wrong question. If you can't make *any* regular expression work, then the problem is not your regex, it's what you are doing with it. You say you have to use it "in xsd", but clearly that's not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^(default|\d{4}(,\d{4})*)$/
```

That's

```
^         start of string
(         start group
 default  literal "default"
 |        or
 \d{4}    digit repeated 4 times
  (       start group
   ,      literal ","
   \d{4}  four digits
  )       end group
 *        repeat 0 or more times
)         end group
$         end of string
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 15 seconds. ;-)

Comment: it does match anything not even 1234
not even 1234,5678

Comment: Works for me at this regex test page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html (Note: I had to remove the slashes at the beginning and the end.) Could there be some other reason that things aren't working for you? Namespace problems, perhaps?

Comment: For XML Schema you would have to remove the anchors (`^` and `$`) as well; XSD regexes are implicitly anchored, so those metacharacters aren't supported.  But that leaves `default|\d{4}(,\d{4})*`, which the OP already said didn't work, so I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: @Alan Moore: I was testing it in a console .NET App. I finally need to move it in XSD.

Comment: @Don Kirby: You are right. It works great in the site you mentioned. I probably have to look into my app.
@Greg: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on replies to the comments, it sounds like you need a regular expression for a pattern restriction in an XSD.  According to the [XSD spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern), this should work:

```
default|[0-9]{4}(,[0-9]{4})*
```